# How to split string and create a random words in php

Tags: php

I want to suggest possible words to my clients like this :

t.est
te.st
tes.t
te.st
tes.t
t.e.s.t

Now my code would be ?

```
<?php 

$string = "test";
$array = str_split($string);

foreach($array as $letter){
    echo $letter.".";
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_shuffle and then some conditional logic/looping to "sprinkle" the `.` throughout the shuffled characters.

Comment: It doesn't seem like he wants to shuffle the characters though?  All of his examples had them in order...

Comment: I have a really convoluted method in my head that is probably far from the best but... here goes.  You get the character count of your string (let's call it x) and then do 2^x-1 to get the amount of permutations you will need (let's call it y.)  For instance, a 3 character string would be 2^2 or 4 permutations... dog, d.og, do.g, d.o.g (make sense so far?)  Then you do a z=0 while z<y loop... so if our y is 4 we will loop through the ints 0, 1, 2, and 3.  (More in next comment...)

Comment: Ok so then within the loop you convert your integers to binary... so in this example you will loop through 00, 01, 10, 11.  And... that binary basically tells you whether you put a dot after a character or not.  00 = dog, 01 = do.g, 10 = d.og, 11 = d.o.g so... yeah.  This will work, it's just uber convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is solves your problem:

```
$string = "test";
$array = str_split($string);


$len = strlen($string);    
$rand_indx = mt_rand(0,$len);


if ($rand_indx == $len) {
    $array[$rand_indx] = ".";
} else {
    for ($x=$len; $x > $rand_indx; $x--) {
        $array[$x] = $array[$x-1];
    }
    $array[$rand_indx] = ".";
}

foreach($array as $letter){

    echo $letter;
}
```

Comment: The 4s should probably be strlen($string) to make it work with any string.

Comment: Absolutely... That would definitely give it more flexibility.